# can a jquery slider control operate dual sliders?

Tags: jquery, image, text, slider

I'm trying to get a block of text slide simultaeneously with an image slider, but the text must be located outside of the image slider (directly underneath in this case.

Anyway of getting the control commands to work two sliders simultaeneously?